# Why am I getting a cross_val_score of 0?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, sample-size, scikit-learn

The following is yielding a score of 0.0! I must be doing something wrong:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

boston = load_boston()
score = cross_val_score(RandomForestRegressor(), boston.data, boston.target, cv=LeaveOneOut())
print(score.mean()) # 0.0 (or a very low score)
```

I would expect a score of over 0.5 for this classifier, given that I can achieve this score using a 50/50 train/test split.

I am using scikit-learn v 0.18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$R^2$ score is not appropriate for LOO cross-validation. Since $R^2$ is a measure of how close the data are to the fitted regression line, it's undefined for a point (a point cannot define a line).

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I get, same version of sci kit.

[image]

Maybe check your default rounding settings?

Comment: That's interesting in itself, but my confusion is about the cause of such a low score. If, instead of leave-one-out, I use something more common like a 5-fold CV, then I get a score > 0.5. In other words, LOO is producing an inexplicably-low score.

Comment: by repeating the script, sometimes I'll get the non-zero (albeit very low) CV score, corresponding to one of the 506 folds scoring 1.0, and the others scoring 0.0.